# How is the variance equivalent to the following?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, variance, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I am working through a problem that asks if the set, $P$ is convex.

*Note that $P$ is a set of pdfs.  Each member $p \in P$ describes a pdf - a vector of real numbers that are probabilities.  The assignment is to determine if the set of all pdfs (all $p$'s) subject to a restriction on the variance, is a convex set.*

These are the restrictions on $p$, including the inequality for the variance of all of all of the $p$'s:

- $p$ is a vector of probabilities, $p \in \mathbb{R}^+$
- probability simplex, which is of course a restriction on $p$
  $P = \{p \,  \vert \sum_{i=1}^{n}{p_i} = 1 , p \ge 0\}$
- $p_i$ is the probability that random variable $x$ is $x=a_i$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $var(x) \ge \alpha\ $and$ \,\,var(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i-E[x])^2}\}$
- $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $var(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i-E[x])^2}$ and $E[x]=\sum_{i=1}^np_ix_i$

**Now, in the Solutions to the homework I see**

In the solutions to my homework, it says that that "$var(x) \ge \alpha$ can be reformulated as $\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i^2+(\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i)^2 \le \alpha$".

This is obviously convex...so I can see the answer from there.

But, my question is how can this inequality $var(x) \ge \alpha$ be reformulated as $\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i^2+(\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i)^2 \le \alpha$ ?

*EDIT* 
Here is the homework question in full.  I am particularly asking about parts (f) and (g):

[image]

And here is the solution:

[image]

If you'd like any more information, please let me know.

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: the set of real numbers

Comment: then write `$\mathbb{R}$` . Btw $\mathbb{R}^+$ would be better, and expression of variance given in the question is confusing...

Comment: The expression for the variance is what is given in the problem statement - but FWIW I happen to agree with you.

Comment: When you say *this set*, what set do you mean?  The set of $p$ vectors such that those equalities and inequalities hold? Or the set of $p$ and $a$ vectors... Or what?

Comment: The use of the term $\operatorname{var}$ is confusing, the variance is a real number, the above is a function. The expression above is a convex quadratic in $x$, and in general, if $\alpha \ge 0$, the set given above is not convex. This is easy to see by looking at the function $t \mapsto \operatorname{var}(Ex+(t,0,0,...,0))$.

Comment: If you are working in $\mathbb R$ the question is  void, hence you are talking with discrete sets, with points. Convexity has sense only on connected, in $\mathbb R^n,n>1$ sets

Comment: If you only have points, you cannot define "straight lines inside the set", and then convexity has no meaning.

Comment: @hyprfrcb you might be correct...but this is what the question says.  Is the question in the textbook wrong?  I tried to clear things up in my edits to the question.

Comment: Still edited, convexity cant be applied over the space of functions, which it is just composed of discrete elements. Maybe on the final PDF...

Comment: @hyprfrcb feel free to write an answer...I'm interested in how convexity cannot be applied over a space of functions.  I'm pretty sure I've seen a few examples of compositions of functions, pointwise maximums, etc.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Yes, convexity here is being applied on the final PDF, which is a set of values.

Answer (score 2):

First we know that
$$
\mathbf{Var}(x) = Ex^2 - (E(x))^2 = \sum_{i=1}^np_i a_i^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i) ^2 \geq \alpha
$$
The set  is equilvalent to
$$
- \sum_{i=1}^np_i a_i^2 + (\sum_{i=1}^np_ia_i) ^2 \leq \alpha
$$
Define $b = [-a_1^2,-a_2^2,...,-a_n^2], A = aa^T $​​​, then  it is equilvalent to
$$
-b^Tp + p^TAp \leq \alpha
$$
With $-b^p, p^TAp$ are both convex function about $x$,  $f(p) = -b^Tp + p^TAp $ is also convex. With the image of $f$ with $f(x) \leq \alpha$, the image of $f$ is convex. Then the inverse image $p$ is also convext.

Proof done.

Note: A is positive semidefinite, such that $p^TAP$ is convex .

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered as is, because we lack a proper definition of "convex" in this setting.

For a complete answer, the **full homework text** is needed.

**Setup**

Let's write in here all the assumptions ans appreciations:

Definitions:

- $\mathscr P$ is a infinite set of discrete pdfs, for **a fixed set** of numbers $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$,
- $f_j$ is a discrete pdf for the random variable $x_j$, described through the vector $p_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $j=1...m$: 
  $$
  f_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}\delta(x-a_{i}), \sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}=1, p_{ij}\ge 0
  $$

Constraint:

- $\text{var}(x) \ge \alpha, \alpha \gt 0$

Applying the definition of variance to the $j$th pdf:
$$
\text{var}\{f_j\}= \sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}\right)^2 \ge \alpha
$$

**Question**

To determine if the set of all $p \in \mathscr P$ subject to a restriction on the variance, is a convex set.

**Possible Interpretations**

- Over the set $\mathscr P$ it is trivial to apply convex combinations, if we assume $\mathscr P$ is infinite,
- Over the domain $\mathbb{R}$, for the area defined by each function $f_j(x)$ it is not possible to interpolate a line, because each pdf is discrete, made of delta impulses, hence the interpolations, if valid, are always above the area, hence not being convex.

**Best interpretation**

A [Convex Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) over a set of pdfs or also called a [Mixture Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) is the pdf obtained by weighting every pdf through non-negative numbers with sum equal to 1:
$$
f_m(x)=\sum_{j=1}^mb_jf_j(x), \sum_{j=1}^mb_j=1, b_j\ge 0
$$

Hence:
$$
f_m(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^m b_jp_{ij} \right) \delta(x-a_{i}) 
= \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_{ij} \delta(x-a_{i})
$$
Note that $\sum \beta_{ij}>1, \beta_{ij}>0$ (why?).

Thus, it is possible to build convex combinations from elements of $\mathscr P$ with or without the given constraint, by definition.

Assuming also than the set $\mathscr P$ is not finite, but $p_i \in \mathbb{R}$ we found from the given operation that $\mathscr P$ is closed under convex combinations, hence $\mathscr P$ is convex trivially. But this is independent on the given constraint, and keeps being a void question.

**Main Comment**

EDIT: 
 - As pointed out, the expression is equivalent to:
$$
\text{var}\{f_j\}= \sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}\right)^2 \ge \alpha
\\
 \sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}\right)^2 \ge \alpha + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^np_{ij}a_{i}\right)^2 \ge \alpha
$$
Which is the opposite to the given answer in (g), hence the set is not convex.

Comment: Thanks, @hyprfrcb.  To answer your question *why?* $\Sigma \beta_{ij} \gt 1, \beta_ij \gt 0$ for practice, I would say:  because for each $j$, $\Sigma p_ij =1$, which means $\Sigma \beta_{ij} \gt 1$.  Also, since each $b_ji \ge 0$, and again $\Sigma p_ij =1$, then $\beta_ij \ge 0$.  correct?

Comment: Also, I would add that I think you should be using $\ge$ instead of $gt$ for those expressions.

Comment: Can you paste the homework full paragraph?

Comment: Sure, yes.  Sorry @hyprfrcb, I actually did not know these solutions were publicly available until Guillermo pointed it out.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: I editted it into the question.

Comment: Also, @hyprfrcb, I guess I was wrong originally.  We are checking convexity of a specific element of the set $P$ ($p$), rather than applying convexity over the entire set $P$.  We are just trying to see if it is true that for ALL pdfs, i.e. all elements of $P$, this variance inequality defines a convex set.  Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a mistake in the solutions you were given (in fact, I suspect this problem is from a class I TA'd, EE364A, due to the similarities in formatting, etc).

The idea is that we can write $\text{var}(x)$ as
$$
\text{var}(x) = \sum_i p_ia_i^2 - \left(\sum_i p_ia_i\right)^2
$$
but note that your expression in this case is wrong in both the inequality direction and sign, since you can't sum both of the terms to get an expression for variance. Additionally, note that we're asking for convexity w.r.t. $p$. This is now *not* a convex function, but rather a concave one. Both notions should be easy to prove from here.

Comment: So this is one of this homeworks? http://stanford.edu/class/ee364a/homework.html......

Comment: @hyprfrcb indeed.

Comment: It appears that the question was copied from that - yes.

Comment: So, @GuillermoAngeris my frustration is confirmed.  The solutions are incorrect even here on the course webpage that you TA'd! https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/hw1sol.pdf

Comment: @Candic3 Interesting, how'd you find that page? It seems like an old set of solutions, where there is, indeed, a mistake! The conclusion of (g) is correct, but the method is not; it's likely someone made a mistake on the +/- sign and then switched the inequality to make it work.

Comment: Also, I never knew of the see.stanford.edu website; interesting, those are probably older lectures/solutions, which would make sense (I only say this because Boyd is surprisingly particular about having the solutions/problems be clean and perfect).

Comment: awesome - please tell him to fix!  the SEE website gets plenty of use and is a great resource.  please encorage him to upload more materials.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris, how can the conclusion of (g) be correct?  As you said in your answer, "this is now *not* a convex function, but rather a concave one".

Comment: @Candic3 The conclusion that the set of $p$ such that $\text{var}(x) \ge \alpha$ is a convex set is correct. This is equivalent to saying $\text{var}(x)$ is quasiconcave, which follows immediately from the notion that $\text{var}(x)$ is concave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64407/discussion-between-candic3-and-guillermo-angeris).